# what is the official term for an XSLT Processor which not only processes the input but also serializes the output?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Technically, the XSLT processor is not required to heed the xsl:output element and it is not required to serialize the result tree at all. Source: http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/

So I was wondering what is the official term for an XSLT Processor which not only processes the input but also serializes the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term used at

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#serialization-feature

is

"A processor that claims conformance with the serialization feature"

In practice nearly all XSLT processors offer the serialization feature as part of the software, but allow the software to be configured/deployed in such a way that serialization is not invoked, e.g. by writing the result tree to a DOM. The spec doesn't really try to distinguish between the capabilities of the processor considered as a software product, and the capabilities of a particular instantiation in a particular environment.